# Load camera inside custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, viewgroup

Im creating a custom ViewGroup using annotations lib.
I want to load the camera in a SurfaceView that is in my ViewGroup. The problem is that when i put my ViewGroup inside my Layout, the camera is not loaded (SurfaceHolder.Callbacks are not called).

Is there a way to put a Camera in my custom View?

My code works fine in an Activity, but in my View its not showing camera.

Thats my code:

```
@EViewGroup(R.layout.activity_custom_camera)
public class TakePictureView extends RelativeLayout implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Context context;
    Activity activity;
    boolean previewing = false;
    Camera camera;
    @ViewById(R.id.camerapreview)
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    @ViewById(R.id.button_take_picture)
    ImageView takepicture;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;
    Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

    public TakePictureView(Context context, Activity activity) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public TakePictureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void bind(){
        activity.getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        surfaceView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (surfaceHolder != null){
                    camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Picture Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        takepicture.setClickable(true);
        takepicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    void takePicture(){

        camera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d("CAMERA", "CRIADA");
        camera = Camera.open();
        Log.d("CAMERA", "CRIADA" + camera.getParameters().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        Log.d("CAMERA", "SURFACE CHANGED");

        if(previewing){
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null){
            try {

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    parameters.setRotation(90);
                }
                else {
                    // This is an undocumented although widely known feature
                    parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                    parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                    // For Android 2.2 and above
                    camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                    // Uncomment for Android 2.0 and above
                    parameters.setRotation(0);
                }
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi How did you called this relative layout in your activity ?

Comment: TakePictureView takePictureView = TakePictureView_.build(getApplicationContext(), SensorActuatorOpened.this);
        takePictureView.bind();
        dynamiclayout.addView(takePictureView);

dynamiclayout is the layout that i use to add my customView.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Instead of extends the view group you should have to extends the SurfaceView & Use the custom class inside your activity and layout. see the below code, It will sure help you.

```
Packager com.test.cam;

public class AdvancePreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    public Camera mCamera;
    public Activity mActivity;


    public AdvancePreview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AdvancePreview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setUpSurface(Activity activity){
        try
        {
            mActivity = activity;
            this.mSurfaceHolder = getHolder();
            this.mSurfaceHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
            this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
            this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        }
        catch(Exceptions e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder(){
        return this.mSurfaceHolder;
    }

    // SurfaceHolder.Callback
     @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  

        Log.print(this.getClass().toString(), "surfaceCreated()");

        try {
                mCamera = Camera.open();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(getSurfaceHolder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // SurfaceHolder.Callback
     @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        Parameters params = null;

        Log.print(this.getClass().toString(), "surfaceChanged()");

        try {

            if (camera != null) {
                params = mCamera.getParameters();

                params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

                mCamera.setParameters(params);

                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // SurfaceHolder.Callback
     @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {       
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mCamera = null;
    }


    public void startTakePicture() {

        Parameters params = null;
        AudioManager mgr = null;

        Log.debug(this.getClass().toString(), "startTakePictre()");

        try {
            mgr = (AudioManager)Const.CONTEXT.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);

            if (mCamera != null){

                params = mCamera.getParameters();

                params.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);

                mCamera.setParameters(params);

                mCamera.autoFocus(new CustomAutoFoucsCallback(activity));
            }else{
                activity.finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }   
}
```

In next step how to use this AdvancePreview class in your activity, see the below code with activity and it layout xml file.

```
Packager com.test.cam;

public class CamActivity extends Activity {

    public AdvancePreview mAdvancePreview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cam_activity);
        mAdvancePreview = (AdvancePreview)findViewById(R.id.advancepreview);
        mAdvancePreview.setUpSurface(this);        
    }

    // class this function on click event of button 
    public void takePicture(){
        mAdvancePreview.startTakePicture(); 
    }
}
```

cam_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <com.test.cam.AdvancePreview
        android:id="@+id/advancepreview"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

For save the captured photo save use the CustomAutoFocusCallback see the below line from AdvancePreview

**camera.autoFocus(new CustomAutoFoucsCallback(activity));**

Let me know if you any question or query. Thank you

Comment: I need to load the View (SurfaceView) dynamically. This is a static way. To use dynamically what i have to change? 
Thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @WitaloBenicio Yes you can remove the declaration of advance preview from xml file. add it dynamically, even you can add the AdancePreview in any of your layout dynamically

Comment: @WitaloBenicio As per my knowledge you should need to read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/COffLpanlz0/discussion